# Hola estoy necesitando ayuda con este problema. El error que me da es este "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)"

Tags: php

> El error se encuentra en el if creo que estoy usando mal las comillas

```
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $salida.="<tr>
          <td>".$fila['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['cedula']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['nombreapellido']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['cargo']."</td>
          <td>".$fila['sistemas'].$fila['equipos'].$fila['redes']."</td>
          <td>".$fila['fecha_add']."</td>
          <td>"
              if ($fila['conformidad'] == 0 ) {
                  "<i class='fa fa-check text-green'>Procesado</i>"
              }else{
                  "<i class='fa fa-remove text-red'>Pendiente</i>"
              }
          "</td>
                    </tr>";
    }
```

*espero que me puedan ayusar con mi problema desde ya gracias*

Comment: Estas colocando un if concatenado a un string, debes cerrar el string, condicionar y volver a abrir o colocar un if ternario.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio. El problema es porque antes del `if` falta `;`. Ademas estas mezclando `String` con código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternativa con [operador ternario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) y [sintaxis de llaves](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

```
<?php
while ( $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
  $salida .= "<tr>" .
  "<td>{$fila['id']}</td>" .
  "<td>{$fila['cedula']}</td>" .
  "<td>{$fila['nombreapellido']}</td>" .
  "<td>{$fila['cargo']}</td>" .
  "<td>{$fila['sistemas']}{$fila['equipos']}{$fila['redes']}</td>" .
  "<td>{$fila['fecha_add']}</td>" .
  "<td>" . (
    0 == $fila['conformidad'] ?
    "<i class='fa fa-check text-green'>Procesado</i>" :
    "<i class='fa fa-remove text-red'>Pendiente</i>"
  ) . "</td>" .
  "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me resolviste mi problema. :)

Comment: @MaicolSilvera entonces marca la respuesta como "aceptada". Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes dudas.

Answer (score 1):

La legibilidad es muy importante a la hora de escribir código.

Te recomiendo que estudies la sintaxis alternativa para estructuras de control.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

```php
<?php while ( $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) : ?>
    <tr>
          <td><?= $fila['id'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $fila['cedula'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $fila['nombreapellido'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $fila['cargo'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $fila['sistemas'] . $fila['equipos'] . $fila['redes'] ?></td>
          <td><?= $fila['fecha_add'] ?></td>
        <?php if ( $fila['conformidad'] == 0 ) : ?>
                  <i class='fa fa-check text-green'>Procesado</i>
        <?php else: ?>
                  <i class='fa fa-remove text-red'>Pendiente</i>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: para mantener la salida en una variable se puede usar [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php) antes del `while` y un [`$salida = ob_get_clean();`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ob-get-clean.php) despues del `endwhile`

Answer (score 1):

Debes concatenar de la siguiente forma:

```
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $salida.="<tr>
          <td>".$fila['id']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['cedula']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['nombreapellido']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['cargo']."</td>
          <td>".$fila['sistemas'].$fila['equipos'].$fila['redes']."</td>
          <td>".$fila['fecha_add']."</td>
          <td>";
              if ($fila['conformidad'] == 0 ) {
                  $salida.="<i class='fa fa-check text-green'>Procesado</i>";
              }else{
                  $salida.="<i class='fa fa-remove text-red'>Pendiente</i>";
              }
          $salida.="</td>
                    </tr>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Saca el if del string

```
<td>";
if ($fila['conformidad'] == 0 ) {
    $salida .= "<i class='fa fa-check text-green'>Procesado</i>";
} else {
    $salida .= "<i class='fa fa-remove text-red'>Pendiente</i>";
}
$salida .= "</td>
```

Comment: ahora me muetra la tabla pero sigue dando un error en la linea del if. "Notice: Undefined variable: string in"

Comment: Disculpa, utilice la variable string y tu salida, modificalo