# No funciona la condicion, Error Parse (T_IF ) en IF

Tags: php, html, condiciones

comillas simples me tira el error, si pongo dobles imprime el IF como si fuera texto, pongo el código 1 que no funciona y el código 2 que si funciona, el 1 lo estoy haciendo para un buscador.

```
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
            
            $fecha = new DateTime($fila['fecha']);
            $fecha_devolucion = new DateTime($fila['fecha_devolucion']); 
            $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_devolucion)->format('%r%a');
        
            $salida.="<tr>
                        <td>".$fila['col1']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col2']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col3']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col4']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col5']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col6']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col7']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col8']."</td>
                        <td>".$fila['col9']."</td>
                    
                            //prueba
                            if(".$dias." <= 0) {
                                '<td style='color:red'>Caducado</td>'
                                    } elseif(".$dias." <= 365) {
                                    '<td style='color:green'>En tiempo</td>'
                            };
                            //prueba
                    
                        <td style='width:5%;'><a href='#?Id=".$fila['id']."'>prueba</td>

                    </tr>";
        }
```

---

```
/*codigo 2*/

    while ($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta))
    {
        $fecha = new DateTime($datos['fecha']);
        $fecha_devolucion = new DateTime($datos['fecha_devolucion']); 
        $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_devolucion)->format('%r%a');
        
    echo '<tr class="row100 body"><td class="cell100 column1">'.$datos["col1"].'</td>';
    echo     '<td class="cell100 column2">'.$datos["col2"].'</td>';
    echo     '<td class="cell100 column3">'.$datos["col3"].'</td>';
    echo     '<td class="cell100 column4">'.$datos["col4"].'</td>';
    echo     '<td class="cell100 column5">'.$datos["col5"].'</td>';
    echo     '<td class="cell100 column6">'.$datos["col6"].'</td>';
    echo     '<td class="cell100 column7">'.$datos["col7"].'</td>';
    echo     '<td class="cell100 column8">'.$datos["col8"].'</td>';
    echo     '<td class="cell100 column9">'.$datos["col9"].'</td>';
    
     if ($dias <= 0) {
            echo '<td class="cell100 column10" style="color:red"></td>';
        } elseif ($dias <= 7) {
            echo '<td class="cell100 column11" style="color:green"></td>';
    }
    echo     "<td class='cell100 column12' style='width:5%;'><a href='#?Id=".$datos["id"]."'>prueba</td></tr>";
```

Comment: ¿Y qué estás tratando de hacer con ese código?, explica un poco que quieres que haga para poder resolver mejor el error :)

Comment: el IF compara la fecha que se registra en mi col fecha e imprime en tiempo o caducado, la cosa que imprime ambos por los td, no funciona la condición, sumando que se descuadra mi tabla :)

Comment: el error es bastante parecido a https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/362142/81450

Comment: gracias!, notifico si hay avances

Comment: @aloMalbarez solucionado :D